# dplyr: access current group variable

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

After using data.table for quite some time I now thought it's time to try dplyr. It's fun, but I wasn't able to figure out how to access

- the current grouping variable
- returning multiple values per group

The following example shows is working fine with data.table. How would you write this with dplyr

```
library(data.table)
foo <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), ncol = 2)
dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 1, 2), b = c(4, 5, 6))

# data.table (expected)
dt[, .(c = foo[, a]), by = a]
   a c
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 2 3
4: 2 4

# dplyr (?)
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  summarize(c = foo[a])
```

Comment: With `summarize`, you may not be able to do it, you may try with `do`

Comment: You are missing a comma in your `foo[a]`... Anyway, as akrun suggested, summarise is not a good fit since it likes to return one row per group. Nor is mutate, which likes to return n() aka .N, so you need to hack something together in the dplyr world.

Comment: hm. thanks. Still no success with: dt %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  do(c = foo[, a])
Could you show me the working snippet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `do` from `dplyr`.  (No other packages used).  The `do` is very handy for expanding rows.  We only need to wrap with `data.frame`.

```
dt %>% 
     group_by(a) %>%
     do(data.frame(c = foo[, unique(.$a)]))
#      a     c
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     1     2
#3     2     3
#4     2     4
```

---

Or instead of `unique` we can subset by the 1st observation

```
dt %>% 
    group_by(a) %>%
    do(data.frame(c = foo[, .$a[1]]))
#     a     c
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     1     2
#3     2     3
#4     2     4
```

---

Or with `dplyr` >= 1.0.0 (EDIT: Based on @Todd West comments)

```
dt %>%
   reframe(c = foo[, cur_group()$a], .by = 'a')
  a c
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 2 3
4 2 4
```

---

This can be also done without using any packages

```
stack(lapply(split(dt$a, dt$a), function(x) foo[,unique(x)]))[2:1]
#   ind values
#1   1      1
#2   1      2
#3   2      3
#4   2      4
```

Comment: As a historical note, dplyr 1.0.0 added [`cur_group()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) for this. So, from May 2020, `cur_group()$a` can be used.

Comment: @ToddWest I would say, with the newer version, you can use `dt %>% reframe(c = foo[, first(a)], .by = 'a')`

Answer (score 8):

You can still access the group variable but it is like a normal vector with one unique value for each group, so if you put `unique` around it, it will work. And at same time, `dplyr` does not seem to expand rows like `data.table` automatically, you will need the `unnest` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
dt %>% 
      group_by(a) %>% 
      summarize(c = list(foo[,unique(a)])) %>% 
      unnest()

# Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

#       a     c
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     2     3
# 4     2     4
```

Or we can use `first` to speed up, since we've already know the group variable vector is the same for every group:

```
dt %>% 
      group_by(a) %>% 
      summarize(c = list(foo[,first(a)])) %>% 
      unnest()

# Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

#       a     c
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     2     3
# 4     2     4
```

Answer (score 1):

To access a grouping variable in a grouped operation (map, walk, mutate), we can refer to `.y` which is exposed automatically within the evaluation context.

Example

```
> iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% group_walk(~{ print(.y) })

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Species
  <fct>
1 setosa
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Species
  <fct>
1 versicolor
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Species
  <fct>
1 virginica
```

This is also documented with more details in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html

> The key, a tibble with exactly one row and columns for each grouping variable, exposed as .y.

Regarding the other proposed solutions: Afaik `do` is not recommended any longer, and the other solution with `unqiue` is imho clumsy (as it requires another reference to the dataframe in question).